# How to properly evaluate this two-variable limit?

Tags: calculus, limits

this is my first post!

I have had no luck with trying to solve this limit.

$$\lim_{x \to 0,y\to 0}
     \left(\frac{5-\sqrt{25-x^2-y^2}} {7-\sqrt{49-x^2-y^2}}\right)$$

The solution should be $7/5$, but no matter what I try I seem to get the wrong answer. If I try to substitute polar coordinates, I get    "$r^2$" in the denominator and if I plug in $r=0$ I can never get the given solution.

If I try to multiply both the numerator and the denominator by $7+\sqrt{49-x^2-y^2}$ I still get  "$r^2$" (after substituting polar coordinates) in the denominator.

Can anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: Since you have done the substitution, why not apply the methods (e.g. L'Hospital rule) for single variable limits?

Answer (score 6):

$$\frac{5-\sqrt{25-x^2-y^2}}{7-\sqrt{49-x^2-y^2}}\cdot \underbrace{\frac{5+\sqrt{25-x^2-y^2}}{7+\sqrt{49-x^2-y^2}}}_{\to \frac57}=\frac{x^2+y^2}{x^2+y^2}=1$$

Answer (score 0):

$\lim_{x \to 0,y\to 0}
     \left(\frac{5-\sqrt{25-x^2-y^2}} {7-\sqrt{49-x^2-y^2}}\right)=\lim_{r \to 0}
     \left(\frac{5-\sqrt{25-r^2}} {7-\sqrt{49-r^2}}\right).$ Now proceed with l'Hospital.